# Searching Microsoft Graph api with spaces in the name

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph to do a search on the `displayName` for a substring of the name. The `$search="displayName:MySearchTerm"` format works perfect. But trying to search on the displayName with a space in the term doesn't seem to work as expected.

Using the sandbox application here
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=groups?$expand=members&method=GET&version=v1.0

If I use the following query format:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$search="displayName:Product vi"&$select=displayName&$orderBy=displayName
```

how can I get it to return only those records that have the term `Product vi` in the `displayName` field.
It shouldn't return any records in the sandbox because the term `Product vi` does not appear exactly in any part of the `displayName` but it currently returns the record `"displayName": "Video Production"`

I've tried the following without success:

```
$search="displayName:"Product vi""
$search="displayName:\"Product vi\""
$search="displayName:\\"Product vi\\""
$search="displayName:\\\"Product vi\\\""
$search="displayName:'Product vi'"
$search="displayName:\'Product vi\'"
```

The `$filter` format is no good to me as it doesn't search the middle of the `displayName` for the string.

How do I format the url to get the desired results if it is even possible?

Comment: where you ever able to find a answer to your question?

Comment: @rread nope - it's still a mystery

Comment: @DeclanMD if you ever find the solution let me know, i want fo search for exactly that file name, and the space make it search for separate words

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use comma instead of the space in `$search` clause.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$search="displayName:Product,vi"&$select=displayName&$orderBy=displayName
```

If `$search` clause contains `"displayName:Product,vi"` then Graph API will search on displayName for "Product vi"

It can require a special request header:

```
ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

Comment: No this doesn't work at all. It finds records with Product, a comma and vi in the displayName. In the sandbox, putting "displayName:Product,la" it finds nothing when it should find 3 records.

Answer (score 0):

Try with %22

instead of

%20

good code...